# How to pause execution of applescript for some time?

Tags: applescript, automator

I have a small applescript in Automator:

```
do shell script "osascript ~/Focus-On.scpt"
delay 60
do shell script "osascript ~/Focus-Off.scpt"
```

Basically, i want to execute the first shell script, then, after a minute, the second one.

But Automator executes both without any delay. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I found: just to pass the job to a shell:

```
do shell script "osascript ~/Focus-On.scpt; sleep 10; osascript ~/Focus-Off.scpt"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the `load script` way, this works on my machine:

```
set homeFolder to path to home folder as text
set scriptOn to load script alias (homeFolder & "Focus-On.scpt")
run scriptOn
delay 60.0
set scriptOff to load script alias (homeFolder & "Focus-Off.scpt")
run scriptOff
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with simple commands inside Focus-Off.scpt, but when there is a lot of code, it just executes without any delay, i just passed job of delaying to shell, with "sleep" :)